# how to iterate JSON array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON data:

```
var obj = {
        "result": [
            [
                {
                    "PARAM 1": [
                        {
                            "field": "firstName",
                            "message": "Parameter is required",
                            "moreInfo": "https://google.com",
                            "responseCode": "-1015"
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "lastName",
                            "message": "Parameter is required",
                            "moreInfo": "https://google.com",
                            "responseCode": "-1015"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "PARAM 2": [
                        {
                            "field": "ZipCode",
                            "message": "Invalid Code",
                            "moreInfo": "https://google.com",
                            "responseCode": "-1020"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
```

I want to get the result base on "responseCode"
I want to display with the following result below.

Example Output:

NAME DETAILS: <-- PARAM 1

- Parameter is required
- invalid mobile number

ADDRESS DETAILS: <-- PARAM 2

- Invalid ZipCode
- Invalid character

Comment: Have you tried anything so far yourself?

Comment: `variableHoldingTheObject.result[0]` contains the array of objects you can iterate over.  It is interesting that the result element is an array of a single element that is an array of multiple elements.  That single element array is slightly odd.

Comment: yeah. I have tried iterating it using javascript. @CertainPerformance.

Answer (score 0):

although the below code works, you would want to consider changing the format of the object that is being created. this could easily run into a lot of problems.

```js
var obj = {
    "result": [
        [
            {
                "PARAM 1": [
                    {
                        "field": "firstName",
                        "message": "Parameter is required",
                        "moreInfo": "https://google.com",
                        "responseCode": "-1015"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "lastName",
                        "message": "Parameter is required",
                        "moreInfo": "https://google.com",
                        "responseCode": "-1015"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "PARAM 2": [
                    {
                        "field": "ZipCode",
                        "message": "Invalid Code",
                        "moreInfo": "https://google.com",
                        "responseCode": "-1020"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
};
var headingArray = ['NAME DETAILS', 'ADDRESS DETAILS'];
obj.result.forEach((elem, index) => {
    var key = "PARAM "+(index+1);
    $("#value").append($("<p>"+headingArray[index]+": <-- "+key+"</p>"));
    elem[0][key].forEach(subElement => {
       $("#value").append($("<li>"+subElement.message+"</li>"));
    })
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: this is good. see my edit. I wanted to output the result like that.

Comment: edited the code to suit your output. just please note that this is NOT at ideal way to do things. structure your objects in a better way.